# New fields aren't created after updating a custom module. DRUPAL 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a custom module on my site. I try to install an update with a new field for my vocabulary, but the field doesn't appear.
hook_update:

```
function mymodule_update_7118()
{
    $field_name = 'field_newfield';

    if ( field_info_field( $field_name ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $field = array(
        'field_name' => $field_name,
        'type' => 'list_integer',
        'settings' => array(
                'allowed_values' => array(
                        'Yes' => 1,         //heard that adding a NO value may cause problems, although it doesn't work with a no value either.         
                ),
        ),
    );

    $field = field_create_field( $field );

    $instance = array(
        'field_name' => $field['field_name'],
        'entity_type' => 'taxonomy',
        'bundle' => 'vocab_name',
        'label' => 'Label',
         'widget' => array(
            'active' => 1,
            'module' => 'options',
            'settings' => array(),
            'type' => 'options_select',
            'weight' => '3',
        ),
    );      
    field_create_instance($instance);
}
```

Logs contain several recordings of Internalization module creating a string to translate this field. Also all needed tables are created in the database, but they are all empty.

Answer (score 0):

For creating a new custom field you must do it like a custom module. The steps can be found out at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/140517/how-to-create-new-field-type

You can find the excellent field_example module from the Examples Module which is always the first place to look. Examples module can be downloaded from https://www.drupal.org/project/examples